# Force Draw() in Xamarin.IOS C#

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working on Xamarin.IOS project, where I wanted to update the screen (by calling override Draw() method), on TouchBegan and TouchEnd of UIView.

```
public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);

    SetNeedsDisplay();
}

public override void TouchesEnded(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    base.TouchesEnded(touches, evt);

    SetNeedsDisplay();
}

public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
{
    //draw in CGContext
}
```

Draw() method is called from TouchBegan only in the first time when I click. After which, Draw doesn't get called until TouchEnd is complete.

Is there a way to force Draw on my TouchBegan (before TouchEnd gets fired).
Something similar to Invalidate() in Android.

This is because, i am drawing different context in TouchBegan and TouchEnd. Hence I want Draw method to be called for sure after each touch event.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

[TouchesBegan](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIResponder.TouchesBegan/) just fires when one or more fingers touches the screen. If you want to call **Draw** method when you have touched the screen and moved your finger please add the method [TouchesMoved](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIResponder.TouchesMoved/):

```
public override void TouchesMoved(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    base.TouchesMoved(touches, evt);
    SetNeedsDisplay();
}
```

Then you can end your drawing in [TouchesEnded](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer.TouchesEnded/p/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSSet/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIEvent/) when your fingers left the UIView.